# How to connect to name-based virtualhosts in vagrant guest?

Tags: apache, vagrant

Inside the box, I have two virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    HostName my.site1
    ...
</Virtualhost *:80>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    HostName my.site2
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I connect to the vhosts inside the guest from the host? In my (host) `/etc/hosts` I have:

```
127.0.0.1 my.site1
127.0.0.1 my.site2
```

Because of the Vagrant's port mapping, the guest is accessible only as `my.site1:port`, e.g., `my.site:3000`. With that, the Apache inside the guest takes me just to the root (the Apache's welcome site). It is the same for both vhosts: `my.site1:3000` and `my.site2:3000`.

`apachectl -S` logs:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80     is a NameVirtualHost
         default server stretch.localdomain (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost stretch.localdomain (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost my.site1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-site1.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost my.site2 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/002-site2.conf:1)
```

Is that because of improper configuration of vhosts or am I missing some point in the name/port or host/guest configuration?

Am I right it should work this way?

```
my.site1:3000 -> contents of my.site1
my.site2:3000 -> contents of my.site2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem here is the networking. I was able to reproduce this problem. **First of all, please disable the port forwarding in Vagrant**. Just comment `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8070` and do a `vagrant reload` .**To get this working, you need to check your host's IP address and then go to your Vagrant file and edit `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "X.X.X.X"` so that the ip address here is actually on the same network as your host. What I did is just incremented the last octet by 1. e.g. My local IP address is 192.168.23.45 so I assigned 192.168.23.46 to the Vagrant guest.**

Once this is done, perhaps, you can save yourself all the trouble by just using [this](https://gist.github.com/mattmezza/2e326ba2f1352a4b42b8) shell script to create Virtual hosts for yourself. I have pasted the output below which you can go through to see that I have setup my two virtual hosts with mysite1 and mysite2 names.

Then just put the host file entries on your host like below:

`192.168.23.46 mysite1
192.168.23.46 mysite2`

And accessing the website using http://mysite1 and http://mysite2. You might want to change the content of the index.php placed by script under the respective document roots so that you can be sure that the requests are being handled by correct virtual hosts since this scripts just deals with the default index.php of apache which will be found under both your document roots.

The other option is to make the Vagrant box available on public network and then 
access it using the public IP and for that, you will have to enable `config.vm.network "public_network"` in your Vagrant file and the rest of the process of creating the Virtual host is the same (Using this script).

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# bash test.sh
Enter the server name your want (without www) : mysite1
Enter a CNAME (e.g. :www or dev for dev.website.com) : mysite1
Enter the path of directory you wanna use (e.g. : /var/www/, dont forget the /): /var/www/mysite1/
Enter the user you wanna use (e.g. : apache) : apache
Enter the listened IP for the server (e.g. : *): *
Web directory created with success !
/etc/httpd/conf.d/mysite1.conf
Virtual host created !
Would you like me to create ssl virtual host [y/n]?
n
Testing configuration
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
Would you like me to restart the server [y/n]?
y
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
======================================
All works done! You should be able to see your website at http://mysite1

Share the love! <3
======================================

Wanna contribute to improve this script? Found a bug? https://gist.github.com/mattmezza/2e326ba2f1352a4b42b8
[root@localhost vagrant]# bash test.sh
Enter the server name your want (without www) : mysite2
Enter a CNAME (e.g. :www or dev for dev.website.com) : mysite2
Enter the path of directory you wanna use (e.g. : /var/www/, dont forget the /): /var/www/mysite2/
Enter the user you wanna use (e.g. : apache) : apache
Enter the listened IP for the server (e.g. : *): *
Web directory created with success !
/etc/httpd/conf.d/mysite2.conf
Virtual host created !
Would you like me to create ssl virtual host [y/n]?
n
Testing configuration
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
Would you like me to restart the server [y/n]?
y
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
======================================
All works done! You should be able to see your website at http://mysite2

Share the love! <3
======================================

Wanna contribute to improve this script? Found a bug? https://gist.github.com/mattmezza/2e326ba2f1352a4b42b8
```

Please let me know in case you need more clarification.