# Cannot ping but can SSH into a Homestead Vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I am using Windows 10 accompanied with VirtualBox and Vagrant. Using latest version of Homestead, which is 8.0.1.

My `Homestead.yaml` is as follows:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\xampp\htdocs\company\upgrade\project2
      to: /home/vagrant/code
    - map: C:\xampp\htdocs\company\upgrade\phpmyadmin
      to: /home/vagrant/phpmyadmin

sites:
    - map: project2.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public
    - map: phpmyadmin.test
      to: /home/vagrant/phpmyadmin

databases:
    - homestead
    - project2

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

As you can see, nothing special.

My `scripts/homestead.rb` is slightly changed to replace:

```
# Configure A Private Network IP
if settings['ip'] != 'autonetwork'
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: settings['ip'] ||= '192.168.10.10'
else
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: '0.0.0.0', auto_network: true
end
```

Into this:

```
# Configure A Private Network IP
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: '192.168.10.10'
```

But as I will describe below, with either case, my problem persists.

So, now that I have everything ready and setup, I execute:

```
vagrant up
```

After that we get all those log messages, until this one (first stall until it's timeout):

```
==> homestead: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '8.0.1' is up to date...
==> homestead: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead: Adapter 2: bridged
==> homestead: Forwarding ports...
    homestead: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 9600 (guest) => 9600 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead: Booting VM...
==> homestead: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    homestead: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead: SSH auth method: private key
```

Here, at `SSH auth method: private key`, we get a stall until timeout, after which I get a set of these log messages:

```
homestead: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
homestead: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
```

After those two, everything continues "normally":

```
    homestead: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    homestead: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    homestead:
    homestead: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    homestead: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    homestead: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> homestead: Machine booted and ready!
==> homestead: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> homestead: Setting hostname...
==> homestead: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> homestead: Mounting shared folders...
    homestead: /vagrant => C:/xampp/htdocs/company/upgrade/homestead
    homestead: /home/vagrant/code => C:/xampp/htdocs/company/upgrade/project2
    homestead: /home/vagrant/phpmyadmin => C:/xampp/htdocs/company/upgrade/phpmyadmin
==> homestead: Running provisioner: file...
    homestead: C:/xampp/htdocs/company/upgrade/homestead/aliases => /tmp/bash_aliases
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
    homestead: grep: unrecognized option '---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
    homestead: Comment: "rsa-key-20190312"
    homestead: AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAh8eQk5ttUOVN5me3LkpdKh8XaJYkIpvvcBhf
    homestead: 1YMixNT3eGFSfGzo2VCJ2V0/Rnfn0MnQJG1pMCBsWLCQWYy7kvWnpV8c1LWWJwc5
    homestead: Za29O0qW+Q8vGevysYnyK/T9IW4z/qij85RHd5/PQVxXBDbtpTClWWa8mcFbmfav
    homestead: zsMhZkVS3FEl+zHYk+O/4Uc8NoLvo2BoQPlhpuIiL1pnlJeefweu7Vn19IsQ6Ur4
    homestead: qR+XGZcur5u/Zy53W83Bw50zPS85lkoKc5uNWoNjQ/xue8th4/BRV3EhOjpowKom
    homestead: zDmf6ShX9+3E3uY0LVMiqE7IWHcsH036kcI+5fFSX9sWL/2XMQ==
    homestead: ---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
    homestead: '
    homestead: Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
    homestead: Try 'grep --help' for more information.
    homestead:
    homestead: ---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
    homestead: Comment: "rsa-key-20190312"
    homestead: AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAh8eQk5ttUOVN5me3LkpdKh8XaJYkIpvvcBhf
    homestead: 1YMixNT3eGFSfGzo2VCJ2V0/Rnfn0MnQJG1pMCBsWLCQWYy7kvWnpV8c1LWWJwc5
    homestead: Za29O0qW+Q8vGevysYnyK/T9IW4z/qij85RHd5/PQVxXBDbtpTClWWa8mcFbmfav
    homestead: zsMhZkVS3FEl+zHYk+O/4Uc8NoLvo2BoQPlhpuIiL1pnlJeefweu7Vn19IsQ6Ur4
    homestead: qR+XGZcur5u/Zy53W83Bw50zPS85lkoKc5uNWoNjQ/xue8th4/BRV3EhOjpowKom
    homestead: zDmf6ShX9+3E3uY0LVMiqE7IWHcsH036kcI+5fFSX9sWL/2XMQ==
    homestead: ---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
    homestead: Ignoring feature: mariadb because it is set to false
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
    homestead: Ignoring feature: ohmyzsh because it is set to false
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
    homestead: Ignoring feature: webdriver because it is set to false
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20190905-992-r7q2nr.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20190905-992-yscmnz.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating Certificate: project2.test
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating Site: project2.test
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20190905-992-c5gl1h.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Checking for old Schedule
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating Certificate: phpmyadmin.test
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating Site: phpmyadmin.test
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20190905-992-ddpbhl.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Checking for old Schedule
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Clear Variables
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Restarting Cron
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Restarting Nginx
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating MySQL Database: homestead
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating Postgres Database: homestead
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating MySQL Database: project2
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating Postgres Database: project2
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Update Composer
    homestead: Updating to version 1.9.0 (stable channel).
    homestead:
    homestead: Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 1.8.6
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20190905-992-1jrdxnk.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Update motd
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20190905-992-ziaa9c.sh
```

Now, on some occasions `composer` would fail saying it couldn't talk to `getcomposer.org`, etc. but for this example it did not, but still, the problem persists:

Now if I ping either `project2.test` or `phpmyadmin.test` from my host machine, I sadly get this in repetition:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\company\upgrade\homestead>ping phpmyadmin.test

Pinging phpmyadmin.test [192.168.10.10] with 32 bytes of data:
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.

Ping statistics for 192.168.10.10:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

And whatever I do: change the network type to `public_network`, change the connection type from: Internal, NAT, Bridged, etc. nothing helps.

I've Googled out everything I could have think of, and I really appreciate help now.

To make things more sad and frustrating, when I run:

```
vagrant ssh
```

I get SSH'd into the box:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\company\upgrade\homestead>vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-55-generic x86_64)


0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


vagrant@homestead:~$
```

And for the sake of the question, I think this might help too:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe3b:5ada  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:3b:5a:da  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5739  bytes 1661215 (1.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3646  bytes 645148 (645.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe94:98e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:94:98:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 60  bytes 9575 (9.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 36  bytes 4544 (4.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 324  bytes 79369 (79.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 324  bytes 79369 (79.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be some issue related to Vagrant networking. If you could try assigning a static IP to Vagrant box from your host's IP range and check if there's any difference. If it doesn't work, you may try assigning a Public IP to your Vagrant box as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57798855/10846194) post.